# Intel XDK Crosswalk - Force Landscape

Tags: android-layout, intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

I made an Android app in HTML5 and I compile it using Intel XDK + Crosswalk. Does anyone know how to force the app to open in landscape mode?

Answer (score 1):

`window.screen.lockOrientation("landscape");` will force landscape in **[Crosswalk](http://crosswalk-project.org)** builds.

here is sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script>
        window.screen.lockOrientation("landscape");
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Landscape</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have not yet added the build controls you need to force opening in landscape in a Crosswalk app. We are working on our Cordova build system, which includes such controls. When that system is working correctly we'll migrate it over to the Crosswalk build system. At that point you should be able to control that aspect of your application.

Comment: I am now able to do it in Crosswalk. I edited the .py file. It's the part where it adds the AndroidManifest.xml and I told it to set the orientation to landscape, instead of undefinded, which did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say that it is possible to set the orientation to landscape if you use Crosswalk. Only problem is you will have to install crosswalk on your own server so that you are able to edit the .py file and edit the part about the AndroidManifest.xml and set the orientation to landscape. So it's not possible yet with XDK but it is possbile on your own server.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the property the manifest.json

you can add the property in file manifest.json

Example:
{
  "name": "my app name",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "orientation": "landscape"
}

With this you will force all app to use landscape orientation.

Reference:
For More information orientation: [Orientation Documentation](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest/orientation.html)
For More information manifest: [Manifest Documentation](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest.html)